# Replacing text in a chart title

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm afraid there's no code in this question, but I'm looking for feedback.
I have a VBA addin called FlexFind (https://jkp-ads.com/excel-flexfind.asp) which I am currently trying to port to office-js.

One of the things you can do with the VBA add-in is search and replace in chart titles.
The VBA tool is smart enough to detect if a chart title contains a formula to a cell. That means replacing in that chart title is only feasible if the tool is set to look in formulas. It will search and replace in the chart title's formula instead. Also, if the tool is set to S&R in Values, it ignores chart titles with a formula. As it should.

How would I detect a chart title with a formula in office-js as there appears to be no method or property to read the chart title formula?

Comment: I'll bet that API hasn't been written yet.

Comment: The ChartTitle class has a setFormula() method. But there's no corresponding getFormula() method. So that will probably come at a later time. 

If it's not listed on the Excel suggestion portal, you can create a request here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/c23f3b77-f01b-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472

Comment: I've posted a request here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/excel-chart-objects-do-not-expose-their-formula/idi-p/3300277